# Error al hacer una consulta con whereIn: representación no válida de texto

Tags: laravel

Tengo problemas con laravel al hacer una consulta con `whereIn`:

```
$data = DB::table('vista_matriculas_todas')
             ->select(DB::raw('meses.mes AS MES,SUM(cantidad) as MAT'))
             ->join('meses', 'meses.id', '=', 'vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte')
             ->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf',[$anio])
             ->groupBy('vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte')
             ->groupBy('meses.mes')
             ->orderBy('vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte','ASC')
             ->get();
```

Este es el error que me sale:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:
>   invalid input syntax for integer: \"2017,2016\" (SQL: select meses.mes
>   AS MES,SUM(cantidad) as MAT from \"vista_matriculas_todas\" inner join
>   \"meses\" on \"meses\".\"id\" =
>   \"vista_matriculas_todas\".\"mes_corte\" where
>   \"vista_matriculas_todas\".\"ano_inf\" in (2017,2016) group by
>   \"vista_matriculas_todas\".\"mes_corte\", \"meses\".\"mes\" order by
>   \"vista_matriculas_todas\".\"mes_corte\" asc)", "exception":
>   "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerde que `$anio` es un string entonces si envias más información la debes separar, ejemplo: 2017 o 2017,2018. Entonces debes hacer un explode por la coma ',' para que te genere un arreglo y eso es lo que pasas al whereIn, ejemplo: `->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf', explode(",", $anio))`

Entonces quedaría:
`

```
  $dataa = DB::table('vista_matriculas_todas')  
            ->select(DB::raw('meses.mes AS MES,SUM(cantidad) as MAT')) 
            ->join('meses', 'meses.id', '=', 'vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte')  
            ->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf', explode(",", $anio))
            ->groupBy('vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte') 
            ->groupBy('meses.mes') 
            ->orderBy('vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte','ASC')
            ->get();

    dd($dataa);`
```

Comment: El problema esta en la variable $anio, lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un filtro de varias consultas: Cuando envio Ejemplo: 2017, me funciona, pero cuando le envio 2017,2016 me aparece el error

Comment: @AndrésCantillo por favor acepta las ediciones de tu pregunta para hacerla mejor visible. Sería genial que leas el [tour] y [ask].

Comment: Claro $anio es un string "2017,2016", debes hacer un explode por la coma ',' para que te genere un arreglo y eso es lo que pasas al whereIn, ejemplo: `->whereIn('vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf', explode(",", $anio)) `

Comment: Funcionó!!!!!!, Muchas gracias, el explode fue la solución. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada recuerde marcar la respuesta como solución, así le es util a otros usuarios!

Comment: @caicedo1089, sería genial que coloques las mejoras de tu comentario a la respuesta para que así èsta sea más concisa, de paso léete [answer] ;)